# Convert Stream<Object[]> to List<Object> using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Stream<Student[]>` object and I need to collect as `List<Student>`

If I use, `obj.collect(Collectors.toList())` then I get `List<Student[]>`

Is there a better way to get this converted?

Comment: The better way is: create stream of `Student` (e.g. from `List<Student>`), then you won't have these problems.

Comment: I have a mapping function which returns Stream<Student[]> so I could not build Stream<Student>

Comment: Change the design then.

Comment: Really, having a `Stream<Student[]>` shows a flaw in the design. If you have the chance, you should try to fix the design instead of trying to find a workaround that would make the badly designed solution work anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<Object> flat = objArrs.stream()
                           .flatMap(Stream::of)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<Object[]> list = ...
List<Object> l = list.stream()
                     .flatMap(arr -> Stream.of(arr))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this? you can using [Stream#flatMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to merge all of `Student[]` in a `List` together.

```
stream.flatMap(students-> Stream.of(students)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The documentation says:

> The flatMap() operation has the effect of applying a one-to-many transformation to the elements of the stream, and then flattening the resulting elements into a new stream.